# What is the easy way to crop a part of image using Python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I have below code to crop a part of image:

```
import cv2

def on_mouse(event, x, y, flags, param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        print("X: {} | Y: {}".format(x, y))

win_name = "Image"
cv2.namedWindow(win_name)
cv2.setMouseCallback(win_name, on_mouse)

img = cv2.imread('park.jpg')
cropImg = img[179:470, 511:645]

cv2.imshow(win_name, img)
cv2.imshow("Crop", cropImg)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

In the above code, you can see that I have defined a function call `on_mouse` which basically gives us the coordinates (x, y) wherever the mouse clicks on the image. This helps in getting the `x1, y1` and `x2, y2` coordinates of the area we want to crop. In below image, I am trying to crop the area of `giraffe`. So I clicked on top left corner near giraffe which gave me the coordinates as `X: 470 | Y: 179` and then I clicked bottom right corner of the giraffe which gave me the coordinates of `X: 645 | Y: 511`. When using them in above code, it gives below output

[image]

Below is the original image:

[image]

How can I crop it and what do these `x1, y1 and x2, y2` denote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(x1, y1) are the coordinates of starting point, while (x2, y2) are the end points in the image. In a rectange you can think of them as top-left corner is (x1, y1) while (x2, y2) is bottom-right corner - or just like width and height.

But while cropping they have a little reverse format

```
cropImage = image[ y1: y2 , x1: x2] 
# or
cropImage = image[ Y: H, X: W ]
```

Answer (score 5):

The logic they designed that different than you think. It looks like:

```
cropImg = img[rowStart:rowEnd, colsStart:colsEnd]
```

It means first 2 couple you need to define **row start** and **end** coordinates which means **Y axis** coordinates and then **column start** and **end** coordinates which means **X axis** coordinates. So the line need to be changed in your code as:

```
cropImg = img[170:511,470:645]
```

Your result will change like :

[image]

Comment: Somehow this ended up being the best way for me to understand the coordinates, thanks.

Comment: You re welcome. Pixelwise things easy to handle